# Get navigationId from HttpCacheHitEvent in Shopware 6

Tags: symfony, shopware, shopware6

I have a subscriber that is listening to `HttpCacheHitEvent` and I would like to find the navigationId for the requested page.

For storefront events I use `$event->getRequest()->getRequestUri()`. But for this event i get URLs like `/navigation/5943fc...`. I currently use the `basename()` function to get the navigationIds of those URLs but that does not seem to be the clean way to do it.

Is there an alternative way to retrieve the navigationId from a HttpCacheHitEvent?

Answer (score 2):

When you subscribe to this event you can't access the `_route` and other parameter attributes as usual, as the cached response will be returned before they are usually set.

```php
$request = $event->getRequest();
var_dump($request->attributes->get('_route'));
// null
```

To solve that issue, you may inject the `router` service when registering your listener.

```xml
<service id="Foo\MyPlugin\CacheHitListener">
    <argument type="service" id="router"/>
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

In your listener you then retrieve your route parameters using the  service and the request object from the event, so you can determine which route is being requested. Depending on the route, you can then go ahead and use parameters of the specific route.

```php
class CacheHitListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $matcher;

    /**
     * @param UrlMatcherInterface|RequestMatcherInterface $matcher
     */
    public function __construct($matcher)
    {
        $this->matcher = $matcher;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [HttpCacheHitEvent::class => 'onCacheHit'];
    }

    public function onCacheHit(HttpCacheHitEvent $event): void
    {
        if ($this->matcher instanceof RequestMatcherInterface) {
            $parameters = $this->matcher->matchRequest($event->getRequest());
        } else {
            $parameters = $this->matcher->match($event->getRequest()->getPathInfo());
        }

        if ($parameters['_route'] === 'frontend.navigation.page') {
            $navigationId = $parameters['navigationId'];
            
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We tried it but the attributes do not contain `_route` during this event.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it isn't that easy as the cache precedes the `RouteListener` where the parameters would normally be set. You'll have to do that manually within your listener instead. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Bonus question: `$parameters = $this->matcher->match($event->getRequest()->getPathInfo());` would not work on different storefronts I believe because it only looks at the path info? What is the reason for the `instanceof` condition?

Comment: And is it also possible to get the context or would that make a different question :D ?

Comment: Please create a new question ;)

Comment: `What is the reason for the instanceof condition?`
I lifted this straight from the `RouteListener`. I think it is just a last line of defense fallback.